# Rails 3 - redirecting users who sign in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm using Devise and Can-Can for my community blog and currently looking for a way to re-direct 'only' the Admins and Moderators to the views/admin/index page directly once they sign in. Not sure if I can do this in the routes.rb or Sign In form? Any help appreciated...

application_controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
protect_from_forgery
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
flash[:alert] = exception.message
redirect_to root_url
end
end
```

routes.rb file

```
root :to => "articles#index"
```

sessions/new.html.erb

```
<h2>Sign In</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

<p><%= f.label :email %><br />
<%= f.text_field :email %></p>

<p><%= f.label :password %><br />
<%= f.password_field :password %></p>

<% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
<p><%= f.check_box :remember_me %> <%= f.label :remember_me %></p>
<% end -%>

<p><%= f.submit "Sign In" %></p>
<% end %>
```

error

```
NoMethodError in Devise/sessionsController#create - 

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:11:in `after_sign_in_path_for'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `application_controller` add something like this:

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if current_user.role?("admin") or current_user.role?("moderator")
      admins_index_path    # Make sure this route exists in your app!
    else
      stored_location_for(:user)
    end
  end

end
```

Alternative (for Devise 1.1.x):

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  def stored_location_for(resource)
    if current_user && (current_user.role?("admin") || current_user.role?("moderator"))
      return admin_index_path    # Make sure this route exists in your app!
    end
    super(resource) 
  end

end
```

Comment: @Jits - how would I integrate your suggestion with the existing app_controller code block? Have posted code. Thx

Comment: I've updated my answer. You should be able to just add this as a new method declaration in your application_controller. What's happening "under the hood" is that it "overwrites" the existing `after_sign_in_path_for` defined by the Devise gem and so Devise picks this up and uses it instead.

Comment: @Jits - thanks but that has generated an error, something to do with def after_sign_in_path_for. Have posted above?

Comment: @ubique - what version of Devise are you using?

Comment: @ubique - ah! The instructions I gave will probably only work on Devise 1.2.x. In any case, would you be able to put your application_controller code on Pastie (or GitHub Gists) so we can have a look?

Comment: @ubique - btw, you will need to modify the code I've provided to suit your application. I.e.: `current_user` needs a `role` method OR change this line to match how you do roles, and so on. So check your error for which line it complains on and see if that line contains some code (like a method/variable) which is invalid.

Comment: @Jits - I didn't know about Gists until you mentioned it.. something learnt today! Here is the code URL, let me know if I have set this up wrong  https://gist.github.com/1000919

Comment: @ubique - OK, so check out: https://gist.github.com/1000971. You need to replace the role strings ("admin" and "moderator") and `admin_index_path` to fit your app.

Comment: @Jits - having a session error in ActionController where it says I cannot re-direct to 'nil'. Have tried all combinations of paths and posted error to 1000971. Can you see the error?

Comment: @ubique - I've added a comment to the Gist. Let's continue there, and if the problem get's resolved we'll come back here :)